# Can someone explain the application of KIRCHOFF VOLTAGE LAW in the figure displayed below?

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws

[image]

NOTE: The capacitor has an initial voltage \$V_{c}(0)=V_{CO}\$ at t=0.

Let, the voltage across the capacitor at time t be \$V_{C}(t)\$.

Let, the voltage across the resistor at time t be \$V_{R}(t)\$.

By KVL, \$V_{C}(t)+V_{R}(t)=0\$

i.e., \$V_{C}(t)=-V_{R}(t)\$

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's all a question of how the voltages are defined. If you call the lower node in your circuit the ground node and if you measure all voltages with respect to ground, then you get:

$$V_C(t)=V_R(t)$$

On the other hand, if you measure \$V_C\$ to ground and if you reverse \$V_R\$ then

$$V_C(t) = -V_R(t)$$

Of course, KVL is always satisfied, no matter how you define your voltages.

Answer (score 0):

Before applying KVL, you must choose reference directions for your voltage variables.

For this simple circuit, a natural choice is put a "+" sign at the top and a "-" at the bottom of both the capacitor and the resistor.  In that case, KVL yields:

\$V_R(t) - V_C(t) = 0 \rightarrow V_R(t) = V_C(t) \$

However, the reference direction of voltage variables is *arbitrary*.  Essentially, think of the choice of reference direction like the choice of which end of the component to put the red lead of your voltmeter.  There's no "wrong" choice.  If you measure a negative voltage, then you know the end where the red lead is placed is actually *negative* with respect to the other end.

So, though it seems "unnatural", it is certainly *valid* to say, place the "+" sign for the resistor voltage variable at the bottom.  In that case, KVL yields:

\$V^*_R(t) + V_C(t) = 0 \$

I starred the resistor voltage variable to emphasize that this is a *different* voltage variable than before, i.e.,

\$V^*_R(t) = -V_R(t) \$

Think of the starred variable as the voltage reading after you switched the position of the red and black leads of your voltmeter.